# unable to change size of font in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am instantiating a UILabel programatically. The label displays numbers in a count down. The problem is I seem unable to increase the font size dispute the fact I have the following code

```
[self.viewAnimation addSubview:lblCounter];
    [lblCounter setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    [lblCounter setMinimumFontSize:30.0];
    [lblCounter setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

The UILabel is plenty big enough to fit size 30 font.

Anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `[lblCounter setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]]`, minimum font size only applies when adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is YES, and regulates how much the font will shrink before cropping takes place.

Comment: spot on. Cant believe I didn't know that, cheers, you have save me some messing around.